# Want to remove spaces between strings in parantheses in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I tried to remove the spaces between strings in parantheses. But it is giving function's address.

```
str = "1791 (AR6K Async) S 2 0 0 0 -1 2129984 0 0 0 0 0 113 0 0 20 0 1 0 2370 0 0 4294967295 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2147483647 0 3221520956 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"

local word = str:gmatch("%(%S+)%" , "")
print(word)
```

In this above string, I just want all things except the space from paranthesis. I am trying to get output like following without any spaces in paranthesis.

```
"1791 (AR6KAsync) S 2 0 0 0 -1 2129984 0 0 0 0 0 113 0 0 20 0 1 0 2370 0 0 4294967295 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2147483647 0 3221520956 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
```

Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

```
str = "1791 (AR6K Async) S 2 0 0 0 -1 2129984 0 0 0 0 0 113 0 0 20 0 1 0 2370 0 0 4294967295 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2147483647 0 3221520956 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"

str2 = str:gsub("%b()" , function(s) return (s:gsub("%s", "")) end)
print(str2)
```

Explanation:
1. Traversing all the strings inside parentheses by using Lua pattern `"%b()"`
2. Removing all spaces inside these strings by using `:gsub("%s", "")`

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the return of `gmatch`; straight from the docs:

> `s:gmatch(pattern)`
>
> This returns a pattern finding iterator. The iterator will search through the string passed looking for instances of the pattern you passed.
>
> ```
> for word in string.gmatch("Hello Lua user", "%a+") do print(word) end
> Hello
> Lua
> user
> ```

However, since Lua's patterns aren't full regular expressions, I'm not sure if what you want is possible in one step. This is as far as I got:

```
for word in str:gmatch("%(.*%)") do 
    newWord = word:gsub(" ", "")
    repWord = word:gsub("%)", "")
    repWord = "%" .. repWord .. "%)"
    str = str:gsub(repWord, newWord)
end
```

This works, but is far from what I'd call a "nice" solution.